# Having trouble with Options

Tags: scala

I feel like I'm using options incorrectly here, but can't see how to use getOrElse properly so that my condition works.

Current bad code:

```
if (car.getWheel.isDefined) {
    car.getWheel.get.getHubCap.isShinierThan(hubcap2)
}
else {
    // Do nothing
}
```

I'd like to use something simple like getOrElse instead of this ugly combination of an if statement and using '.get'. A match expression would do the same thing as the if statement, but again take up three lines and basically be reinventing Option. Is there some method in Option that lets me do nothing to Nones?

My goal: If the option contains None, I'd like to have the line of code accomplish *nothing*. I don't want to call getHubCap on some parameter of getOrElse.

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `map`:

```
val result: Option[Boolean] = car.getWheel.map(_.getHubCap.isShinierThan(hubcap2))
```

The code inside `map` will execute only when the `Option` is `Some`. It's treating the Option type as a list with one or no elements. When you map on an empty list you just get an empty list back; when you map on a single-element list, you get a new single-element list but with a mapped value

Comment: getWheel returns a single wheel unfortunately, but also I don't see how mapping would get rid of potential Nones?

Comment: Cool, didn't know what about map. Thanks, marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use map to separate out my cases. The `case _` could important because it is the default case and will match if none of the prior cases matched. This lets you code in a predictive manner and handle all edge cases.

As you can see it is also possible to add conditions by using `if` clause within the case statements.

```
val opt: Option[String] = Some("foo")

val printString: String = opt match {
  case Some(string) if string == "bar" => string
  case Some(string) => string
  case _ => "none"
} 

println(printString)
```

Comment: This doesn't work—you mean `match` probably instead of `map`—and in any case `case _` is usually an antipattern in my view. Let the compiler tell you if you haven't handled all cases.

Comment: Oops you are absolutely correct, changed it to match. As for `case_` I do think there is a place for it. It can represent all cases that are not of concern. For example if there are 10 cases but you only care for the first.. Simple handle the other 9 with the default case